# How do i make a panel pop out visually?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, styling

I would like to make my panel pop out instead of going inside the form. I don't know if that visual studio related or no but i only have a Fixed3D style, which makes the panel go in, and a FixedSingle which adds a blacks border around the panel. But i would a panel that goes out, to make that kind of a pop out style Here's an example:

[image: Example]

Is this visual studio related or i can somehow make it look like this? That example image is from borland (delphi).

I'm using WinForms for this.

It's not a duplicate i want the panel to be raised and i even attached an image. The other topic is a bout thickness of the border which isn't what i asked for. I didn't find any example of how to make a panel raised to look like its pop out.

Comment: What framework are you using? WPF/WinForms?

Comment: @S.Petrosov I'm using WinForms

Comment: If you will try and couldn't do this write to me in chat I will send you on of the available solutions

Comment: `public class Panel3d: Panel
    {
        public Panel3d()
        {
            DoubleBuffered = true;
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(SystemPens.ButtonHighlight, ClientRectangle);
            e.Graphics.DrawLines(SystemPens.ButtonShadow, new[] {new Point(Width -1, 0),
                new Point(Width -1, Height - 1), new Point(0, Height - 1) } );
        }
    }`

Comment: @TaW Thank you, i'll try that.